# how to change the Json format output

Tags: angularjs, json, spring

I have an entity named Activite that references itself, (an Activite can have many activite) and I'm trying to get all the activite through a rest service.
this is the entity:

```
@Entity
public class Activite implements Serializable{
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id_act;

private String designation_fr;
private String designation_ar;
private String libelle;

@ManyToOne
private Activite parent;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
private Collection<Activite> children;

public Collection<Activite> getChildren() {
    return children;
}
public void setChildren(Collection<Activite> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
@JsonIgnore
public Activite getParent() {
    return parent;
}
public void setParent(Activite parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

this is the Json format that I'm getting:

```
[{
"id_act": 1,
"designation_fr": "fr",
"designation_ar": "cfd",
"libelle": "Activite 1",
"children": [
{
 "id_act": 11,
 "designation_fr": "bhjf",
 "designation_ar": "dhbf",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.1",
 "children": [],
 "id_prj": 1
 },
 {
 "id_act": 12,
 "designation_fr": "njkj",
 "designation_ar": "ffrgrn",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.2",
 "children": [],
 "id_prj": 1
 },
 {
 "id_act": 13,
 "designation_fr": "njkdj",
 "designation_ar": "frjn",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.3",
 "children": [
 {
 "id_act": 131,
 "designation_fr": "hcchchc",
 "designation_ar": "GFVVHG",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.3.1",
 "children": [],
 "id_prj": 1
 }
 ],
 "id_prj": 1
 }
 ],
 "id_prj": 1
 },
 {
 "id_act": 11,
 "designation_fr": "bhjf",
 "designation_ar": "dhbf",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.1",
 "children": [],
 "id_prj": 1
 },
 {
 "id_act": 12,
 "designation_fr": "njkj",
 "designation_ar": "ffrgrn",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.2",
 "children": [],
 "id_prj": 1
 },
 {
 "id_act": 13,
 "designation_fr": "njkdj",
 "designation_ar": "frjn",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.3",
 "children": [
 {
 "id_act": 131,
 "designation_fr": "hcchchc",
 "designation_ar": "GFVVHG",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.3.1",
 "children": [],
 "id_prj": 1
 }
 ],
 "id_prj": 1
 },
 {
 "id_act": 131,
 "designation_fr": "hcchchc",
 "designation_ar": "GFVVHG",
 "libelle": "Activite 1.3.1",
 "children": [],
 "id_prj": 1
 }
 ]
```

and this what I want to get:

```
[
      {
            "id_act": 1,
            "designation_fr": "fr",
            "designation_ar": "cfd",
            "libelle": "Activite 1",
            "children": [
              {
                "id_act": 11,
                "designation_fr": "bhjf",
                "designation_ar": "dhbf",
                "libelle": "Activite 1.1",
                "children": [],
                "id_prj": 1
              },
              {
                "id_act": 12,
                "designation_fr": "njkj",
                "designation_ar": "ffrgrn",
                "libelle": "Activite 1.2",
                "children": [],
                "id_prj": 1
              },
              {
                "id_act": 13,
                "designation_fr": "njkdj",
                "designation_ar": "frjn",
                "libelle": "Activite 1.3",
                "children": [{
                    "id_act": 131,
                    "designation_fr": "njkdj",
                    "designation_ar": "frjn",
                    "libelle": "Activite 1.3.1",
                    "children": [],
                    "id_prj": 1
                  }],
                "id_prj": 1
              }
            ],
            "id_prj": 1
          }]
```

As you can see Activite with the id 11 12 13 and 131 are duplicated I want them to be only in the children array
I'm  actually calling the rest service in angularjs so is it possible to change the json format that I'm getting with angularjs or should I change the query in the back-end

Comment: If you have to change the structure of something you send to the client, it is better to do it server side

Comment: what is the difference between these two json?

Comment: Are you just referring the indentation in the JSON format or something else ?

Comment: the objects that are in the children array are duplicated I want to get them only in the children array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have pasted the **response json** above. Its better to change the back-end code to get proper json which you need, so that you can just consume the json for further processing.

Comment: how can I avoid the duplication of the objets that are in the children array ??

Comment: please check the condition where you are generating the json in back-end.

Comment: I'm fetching the data with the  Jpa repository method findAll